# Matching tag in HTML keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio (2008) that will allow me to jump to matching HTML tag... as CTRL+] does for matching braces when you are in code view?

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table|>
```

Cursor is on closing table tag and I would like to press something like CTRL+] to jump to opening table tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: VS 2015 supports that. Please, see the answer from Steve Cooper.

Comment: @Christian - I'm not sure it does.  It appears to support jumping between the opening `<` and closing `>` of the same tag (i.e. `<div>`), but it doesn't jump between the opening `<div>` tag and closing `</div>` tag as requested by the OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok here is the answer  as macro which i've built which does it (toggle ) including go to focus :

Here is the demo :

[image]

And here is the code  , enjoy !

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module Module2
    Sub beginToEnd()

        'Place cursor somewhere in beginning tag, run macro, to select from beginning to End Tag

        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim objSel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim topPoint As TextPoint = objSel.TopPoint
        Dim lTopLine As Long = topPoint.Line
        objSel.GotoLine(lTopLine, False)
        '  DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim line1 As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text()
        If InStr(line1, "</") Then

            ' MsgBox(line1)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText, True)
            objSel.GotoLine(lTopLine, False)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")


        Else

            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(False)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")

        End If
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim line2 As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text()
        Dim objSel3 As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim topPoint3 As TextPoint = objSel3.TopPoint
        Dim lTopLine3 As Long = topPoint3.Line
        objSel.GotoLine(lTopLine3, False)
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText, False)


    End Sub



End Module
```

Comment: No longer supported out of the box. This requires the dev labs visual studio extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio

Answer (score 66):

I search and couldn't found direct short cut. But you can use..

If you want to go starting matching HTML tag, then follow below steps.

1. Place cursor at ending matching HTML tag.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> [To Collapse entire tag]
3. Press <kbd>Home</kbd> Key [To place cursor at before starting tag]
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> [To Expand entire tag]

If you want to go ending matching HTML tag, then follow below steps.

1. Place cursor at starting matching HTML tag.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> [To Collapse entire tag]
3. Press <kbd>End</kbd> Key [To place cursor next to ending tag]
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> [To Expand entire tag]

Comment: This doesn't seem like something that could really be called a shortcut. Clever, though.

Comment: Clever! Works for XAML as well

Comment: The `Ctrl+]` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39287838/336753) actually works in 2019.

Comment: @kub1x not in my VS... Crtl+] moves you between the start and the end within a tag... not from the start tag to the end tag.

Comment: This is really a lifesaver man

Answer (score 13):

In Visual Studio **2015**, this is now supported with the usual bracket matching keystrokes;

- `ctrl+]` jumps from the start tag to the end tag.
- `ctrl+shift+]` selects everything between the start tag and the end tag.

It seems pretty sensitive, though, and to select an entire tag and its contents you need to start right on the `<` that opens the tag.

Comment: As of the current date this is should be the most appropriate answer.

Comment: Hmmm... this isn't working for me in VS2015  Using `ctrl+]` jumps from the opening `<` of the tag to the closing `>` of the tag itself... it is **not** jumping between the opening `<div>` tag and the closing `</div>` tag

Comment: Yeah, as I say, it's sensitive to the position of your cursor, which must be exactly before the opening less-than -- `I<`. Otherwise, it's anyone's guess where it'll end up.

Comment: What about Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Not sure about previous versions, but in VS2017: when cursor is placed anywhere on openning tag name or the `<`, **first** `Ctrl+]` goes to the `>` of the openning tag, and the **second** press of `Ctrl+]` goes to position after the closing tag. The **third** press goes back to the first character of the openning tag. Hold `Shift` to select/unselect along the way. Season to taste. Love it!

Answer (score 8):

After http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ is installed CTRL+] for matching braces works in HTML edit mode...

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2012, in 'source' view, right at the bottom of the document window, there is a breadcrumb-trail-style description of the DOM. You can click at any point to select.

It's not a keyboard shortcut, but it does give you the selection behaviour you're looking for, and you don't need to match tags by eye any more.

(Edit)  If you hover over the breadcrumb, you will see a dropdown arrow. Click the down arrow and click  "Select Tag Content". Then you can just scroll up or down until you find text that is not highlighted.

Comment: If you hover over the breadcrumb, you will see a dropdown arrow. Click the down arrow and you will see, an option to "Select Tag Content". Then you can just scroll up or down until you find text that is not highlighted.

Comment: YES, @DanB this feature was available in VS 2012, for some reason its not in vs 2015, why did they get rid of it? or is there a option in VS to display it like a window. can't seem to find it

Comment: Good one ! works like a charm in vs2017 too

Answer (score 2):

This totally works when you open a HTML file with the XML Editor (Right click -> Open With... -> XML Editor).

Comment: LOL ;) this is so funny... now I only need to setup intellisense for HTML in XML view.

Comment: Yeah, this should be the default behavior for an HTML document. Maybe it works with a XHTML document. If it doesn't work by default, you can add a schema file to a xml document like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asct4hkz%28VS.71%29.aspx. Here are the schemas for xhtml: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/#schemas. Also, you can add the xml schema to the schema cache as specified here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255816.aspx. I hope this helps you out with intellisense.

Comment: Yeah - I already know how to add intellisense to certain types - just I probably won't be doing all this just get keyboard shortcut working. If I start doing anything - it'll probably be coding of AddIn if this isn't supported.

Comment: Like a teacher of mine said: Well, you can always program it :P

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that in Visual Studio 2010, not in the current version or in older ones. Maybe the next version will have this feature.

Comment: nice that you pointed that out, otherwise people might have thought you where talking about the future.

Comment: You should state version # instead of 'current'. VS 2012 is released and now 'current' means something else than what u intended. We have to look at the message date to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio Code in Windows 10. Currently version 1.34.0. To jump to the matching html tag, I set it up through File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. Look for "Matching Tag: Jump to matching tag" .. There's a + when you hover it, then I set keybinding `Shift + ]` .. you can set your own as long as it isn't used for another function. So now I am able to jump to the closing HTML tag. Hope this helps.

Comment: Topic starter asks about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

- **SOLUTION WORK FOR ME:**

press **`ctrl+shift+p`** this opens command pallete  , after that write **`emmet:go to matching pair`** in **search bar**.

Click on `setting` icon and set your shortcut key(if you want). I uses **`ctrl+shift+/`** and press **enter.**
**It definitely works.**

Comment: Topic starter asks about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code