# Shortcut key to go to the end of the html tag in asp.net

Tags: html, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matching tag in HTML keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738573/matching-tag-in-html-keyboard-shortcut)

Is there any shortcut key in ASP.net to go to the end of the tag like in following html if I am on `<div>` tag and I want to go to `</div>` then I have to scroll down to the end.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In complex pages markup is huge and scrolling up and down waste a lot of time so if there is no short cut key then any suggestion that how to go to he end tag and start tag as quickly as possible using keyboard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been asked and answered here: [Matching tag in HTML keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738573/matching-tag-in-html-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: Thanks, I have searched before posting question but could not find it.