# Easy way to delete an html tag and its content in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a way to delete an html tag and its content in Visual Studio with the fewest keystrokes?

Addition:

The tag is several pages long. Resharper or any extension?

Comment: Sure. Highlight from beginning to end of tag, right-click, cut.  0 keystrokes.

Comment: I believe this has been asked before. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738573/matching-tag-in-html-keyboard-shortcut][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738573/matching-tag-in-html-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: @mellamokb  see the addition. It's not that simple! I have to find the end tag, start highlighting and remember where the start tag was.

Comment: @Chat If I can use the ] and highlight at the same time, that would work.